# Syntactic structure of “International Women’s Day”

Tags: syntactic-analysis, possessives, noun-phrases, adjective-position

According to the general rule, in possessive phrases -‘s is placed right between the Possessor Phrase and the Thing-Possessed Phrase.

On the 8th of March one celebrates the International Day of Women. *International* is clearly dependent on *Day*, not on *Women*, so, figuratively speaking, *international day* is the Thing-Possessed Phrase, and *Women* is the Possessor Phrase.

How come we say *International Women’s Day* instead of *Women’s International Day*?

Comment: I'd say it's a proper name consisting of the genitive NP "Women's day" modified by the adjective "International".

Comment: Traditionally “Women’s Day” is analyzed as a Determiner Phrase headed by the Possessive Suffix, not as an NP. 
So, -‘s here serves as a determiner that is the head of the entire phrase together with the adjective. That is why we do not use the article in the beginning.

Comment: I'd say that the genitive "Women's Day" is an NP with "day" as head and "women's" as genitive NP. This we have one NP functioning in the structure of another. Some might say that the genitive NP is a subject-determiner, but that doesn't mean that "women's is not an NP since it has an NP as head.

Comment: @BillJ, thank you! That’s exactly how I see it now, and it does make sense.